# Full width android textView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I am new to ***android*** and I am developing a card making application. I want to add a feature in the app which enables the user to apply *background color* to the textView with *full width*. I need it like the below image:
[image]

This works fine when the text length is long but, when the text contains more than one line and not in full width, it becomes like the below image:

[image]

I need result same as the first image no matter how long the text is. In textView I have used ***wrap_content*** for height as well width. I need to apply background to the textview in full display width even if textView with letter A only. I hope its clear. Thanks

Comment: set width match

Comment: have you changed to width of the textview to match_parent?

Comment: Put your xml code here

Comment: set your _layout width_ to "match_parent" and gravity(not layout_gravity) to "center" also set background color of your choice in xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this set your `textview` **width** to  `match_parent.`

[android:layout_width](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)   :-> 
   **Specifies the basic width of the view.**

**sample code**

```
<TextView    
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**or  set  LayoutParams of textview programatically like this**

```
LayoutParams My_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);    
textview.setLayoutParams(My_params);
```

Comment: Hi ! I have tried but its same as wrap_content...there no any changes. I want apply background color full width but its apply only behind text

Comment: hellow @Priya didn't get you

Answer (score 2):

Sample code:

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="Some Text"
    android:background="#424242" />
```

Comment: Programmatically, it looks like this "id_button_yours.Maxwidth(int)" this code should be inside onClicklistener of that button

Answer (score 1):

```
textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);

your_textview.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

set your **textview width match_parent.**

```
<TextView    
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the width of your TextView from "wrap_content" to "match_parent" :

```
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
/>
```